# Using bukkit plugin to disable other plugin, receive error saying ""plugin" is null"

Tags: java, bukkit

I've coded a Minecraft Bukkit plugin and I'm working on coding another one that can disable the first on command. I have this in my code:

```
Plugin blockProt = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("BlockProt");

Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(blockProt);
```

But when I run the command, I get this error in the terminal:

```
[11:19:36 WARN]: Unexpected exception while parsing console command "play skedwars_eight_one"
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'play' in plugin Ultra_Skedwars v1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:146) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:666) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:629) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:416) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:379) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:713) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:616) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin.isEnabled()" because "plugin" is null
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:425) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at me.creodo.ultraskedwars.Executor.onCommand(Executor.java:40) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        ... 8 more
```

Any help, advice, or input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin()` method will try to find the plugin which have for name "BlockProt" in your case.

It can return null if it don't find the plugin. But, how can you avoid it ?

1. Check if the plugin exist/is enabled. It's better when you have lot of plugin, and you are sure that your plugin don't run BEFORE enabling of other plugin (i.e. at startup)

```
PluginManager pm = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
if(pm.isPluginEnabled("BlockProt")) {
   pm.disablePlugin(pm.getPlugin("BlockProt"));
}
```

2. Try to disable it, but stop if the plugin can't be found. It will more be like your actual code.

```
Plugin pl = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("BlockProt");
if(pl != null) {
   Bukkit.getPluginManager().disablePlugin(pl);
}
```

Don't forget to put in `softdepend` the plugin name that you are managing (here "BlockProt"), and also be sure it's the good name and the plugin is well on your server.